# c# close an form and open an other form after logging in

Tags: c#, forms

So, what I have is an form that has an login code in it and it works fine. But what I want is that after somebody logged in, the login form will be invisible and the main form visible again.
My login form is called `Form1.cs` and my main form )that has to be opened after logging in ' is called `zzz.cs`.

Here is my code that has to do the trick:

```html
MessageBox.Show("You are logged in successfully");
zzz zzz = new zzz();
zzz.ShowDialog();
this.Visible = false;
```

Here is a screenshot what I get:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAym8.gif)

How can I fix this working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the code will stop on the ShowDialog() until the window is closed, replace this with Show().

```
MessageBox.Show("You are logged in successfully");
zzz zzz = new zzz();
zzz.Show();
this.Visible = false;
```

Comment: If `Form1.cs` is your startup form, then hiding it will cause your app to not properly exit until it is closed (unless you explicitly call [Application.Exit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx) from somewhere).  You'd need to add additional code to close Form1 when your `zzz` instance is closed, or pass the reference to Form1 off so that it can be closed from somewhere else.